# LWC connect phase error: [undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name')]

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, community

I am getting

> Error during LWC component connect phase: [undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name')]

on my page when loading this lwc component:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getItem from '@salesforce/apex/CustomBreadcrumbsController.getItem';

export default class KbCustomBreadcrumbs extends LightningElement {
    siteURL = null;
    result = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        const currentPageUrl = window.location.href;
        this.siteURL = currentPageUrl.match(/\/s\/(.+?)(?=\/|#|\?|$)/)[1];
        console.log('Current page URL:', this.siteURL);
        this.getItemData();
    }

    getItemData() {
        getItem({ siteURL: this.siteURL })
            .then(result => {
                this.result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log('Result:', result)
                
                if (this.result.Name) {
                    console.log('Item Name:', this.result.Name);
                }
                if (this.result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r) {
                    console.log('Menu Item Name:', this.result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name);
                }
                if (this.item.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r) {
                    console.log('Sub Menu Item Name:', this.result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

html:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <span>{result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

and apex contoller:

```
public with sharing class CustomBreadcrumbsController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c getItem(String siteURL){
        return [SELECT Name
                ,ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.name
                ,ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.name
                ,ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.name
                ,ccnavmenus__URL__c
                FROM ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c 
                WHERE ccnavmenus__URL__c =:siteURL];
       }
}
```

I can get result.Name but anything deeper in the result structure gives me error. i suspect its something with handling the proxy file. I am lost and couldn't find anything relevant help online.

I can see all the data properly in console.

```
[Log] Result: – {Name: "Založení", ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c: "a0q0E00000BW2BJQA1", ccnavmenus__URL__c: "plus-ucet-zalozeni", …} (aura_prod.js, line 55)
{Name: "Založení", ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c: "a0q0E00000BW2BJQA1", ccnavmenus__URL__c: "plus-ucet-zalozeni", Id: "a0q0E00000BWNidQAH", ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r: Object}ObjectId: "a0q0E00000BWNidQAH"Name: "Založení"ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c: "a0q0E00000BW2BJQA1"ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r: {Name: "Účet Plus", ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__c: "a0q0E00000BW2B4QAL", Id: "a0q0E00000BW2BJQA1", ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r: {Name: "Osobní účty", Id: "a0q0E00000BW2B4QAL"}}Objectccnavmenus__URL__c: "plus-ucet-zalozeni"Object Prototype
[Log] Item Name: – "Založení" (aura_prod.js, line 55)
[Log] Menu Item Name: – "Účet Plus" (aura_prod.js, line 55)
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because the template doesn't check for null values first, so the first render cycle crashes. Add a guard to check for this first:

```
<template>
  <template lwc:if={result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r}>
    <div>
      <span>{result.ccnavmenus__Menu_Item__r.Name}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
```

Also note that is technically an error to initialize to an array first, since you intend to use it as an object, so you should change that as well:

```
result = {};
```

Comment: I did that before, but the if statement was on the wrong level.I Initialy tried to access this value throught result.data and didnt fix this after. I spent whole afternoon on this. Thank you.

Comment: @MatejN Glad I could help!